# How to call gulp tasks with arguments from another gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using the `yargs` npm module to send arguments to my gulp tasks from the console like so;

`$ gulp dev --minify`

However, I can only send arguments on the initial run from the console. Is there a way I could send arguments to tasks from another gulp task? Sort of like this;

```
gulp.task('dev', function() {
  if (yargs.argv.minify) {
    gulp.start('css --minify');
  }
});
```

I need this because otherwise I have to make a sepparate task for dev and production css builds, when I could just do one task with an optional parameter like with grunt.

Comment: I would recommend that you don't rely on a flag, and instead take advantage of gulp tasks. Gulp is not grunt, so you shouldn't use it as such.

Comment: you can use `gulp.pipe` to automate the tasks and pass arugments from one task to the next task.

Comment: How do you propose I add options to gulp tasks upon calling them @sdgluck? I find it pretty dirty to have to create a separate task when just one line of code inside the entire task changes.